# Creating a style guide / pattern library with gulp

Tags: gulp, filenames

I know there is already a tonne of automated tools to create a style guide / pattern library but in the interest of learning I'd like to see if I can roll my own.

Compiling the SASS is straight forward. Same with the js. I can also see how to wrap blocks of HTML from multiple files with a class and compiled into a single file. Ideal for displaying all the 'partials' together on one page.

```
gulp.task('inject:wrap', function(){
return gulp.src('./_patterns/*/*/*.html')
/// get the partial html filename here and insert below @@@
    .pipe(inject.wrap('<div id="@@@" class="pattern">', '</div>'))  
    .pipe(concat('patterns.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('process', ['inject:wrap']);
```

What I struggling with is how I can get the filename of the block - let's say _button.html - and pass this to the wrapper as the element id "@@@" above. Which I can then use to build the style guides navigation / anchor links.

Comment: Why don't you use a template engine, like jade or handlebars? I can send you some sample code I've written, it works with jade, fetches file / folder names and does more complicated stuff...

Comment: Thanks Soheil. I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to achieve but fn looks like it might be useful.

Comment: I would suggest trying https://github.com/karlisup/chewingum or http://fractal.build/guide. Both are template engine agnostic pattern librariy/ style guide/ documentation generators.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code I've got, uses jade template language (which takes care of injections, partials, evaluation etc. by itself); There are two tasks, one generates static HTML pages, other pre-compiles templates to be used as runtime template functions wrapped in AMD

```
// preprocess & render jade static templates
gulp.task('views:preprocess', function () {
  return gulp.src([ 'source/views/*.jade', '!source/views/layout.jade' ])
    .pipe(plumber()) // plumber, because why not?
    .pipe(data(function (file) {
      // prepare data to be passed to the template
      // here we can use the file name to map specific data to each file
      return _.assign(settingsData, { timestamp: timestamp });
    }))
    // render template with data
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destination'));
});


// precompile jade runtime templates
gulp.task('views:precompile', function () {
  // grab folder names
  var folders = fs.readdirSync('source/templates').filter(function (file) {
      return fs.statSync(path.join('source/templates', file)).isDirectory();
    });

  // create a separate task for each folder
  var tasks = folders.map(function (folder) {
      return gulp.src(path.join('source/templates', folder, '*.jade'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        // pre-compile the template as functions, for runtime
        .pipe(jade({
          client: true
        }))
        // wrap it in AMD, so we can use stuff like require.js to fetch them later
        .pipe(wrap({
          moduleRoot: 'source/templates',
          modulePrefix: 'templates',
          deps: [ 'jade' ],
          params: [ 'jade' ]
        }))
        // concat all the templates in each folder to a single .js file
        .pipe(concat(folder + '.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(header(banner, { package: packageData }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('destination/scripts/templates'));
    });

  return merge(tasks);
});
```

Modules I've used are `merge-stream`, `path`, `gulp`, `fs`, `gulp-data`, `gulp-jade`, `gulp-plumber` etc.
Didn't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but I hope this gives you some clues.